# How to play audio/video within user specified time frame in MPMovieplayer

Tags: ios, audio, video, mpmovieplayer

I want to play a video within a user specified time interval. I am using `MPMoviePlayer`and my video is playing. Now I want to set the time frame that video should play. Let's say my video duration  5mins. when click on the video user can specify the time that how long he want to watch or listen. If he give 10minuts, my 5 mins video should play 10mins if he specify 2 mins, my 5 mins video should play only 2 mins.

How can I do this using `MPMovieplayer`
Please help me, thanks

Comment: How can a 5 mins video play 10 mins????

Comment: after finish the video it should check how long remaining,, then another 5 mins remaining, it should start it again. should play repeatedly untill the user given time period end

Answer (score 0):

How about using a timer to set the time that video should play.
The code in swift version:

```
let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 'your_Time_Interval', target: self, selector: "stopVideo", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func stopVideo()
{
    MPMovieplayer.stop()
}
```

If the time bigger than the time of the video, you could just use the same timer concept to play the video again. But remember to stop it when time up.

Hope this solution could help you!